# Indexing TenantID in Multi Tenant DB

Tags: sql-server, indexing, multi-tenant, performance

I am creating a multi tenant db for an application. I have gone with the TenantID in every table approach and it works very well. I am at the performance tuning stage.

My question is should each TenantID in every table be indexed for optimized searching as every query on the db will filter on this column?

Look forward to any advice.

Thanks

Comment: Is this to say that tenantID isn't a FK to all the tables and thus a index by default of being a FK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although there are many considerations you need to make when indexing, In my experience, the (unique) clustered index works well as `tenantId + PK` All PK queries can seek on the composite key.

This has the added advantage of putting the tenantID in your nonclustered indexes as SQL Server uses the clustered key as the reference back to the table from the nonclustered indexes.

Watch out for page splits though, since inserts will almost always be mid page, this approach definitely optimizes for reads. Consider a fill factor of 70 and watch your fragmentation, be sure to have regular index maintenance in place (you want this anyway)

Best of luck.

Comment: By Unique clustering index, do you mean setting up each table to have a composite primary key made of the tables current primary key and the TenantID? Or do you mean setting up a custom clustering index on the table?

Comment: You could go either way. I'm assuming you have an identity or the like as a primary key on the tables. In that case, technically the tenant id is not part of the primary key and it may be difficult to make a composite key if you have FKs set up already. What I did the last time I went down this route was create a unique clustered index on tenantid and the identity column and a non-clustered primary key on the identity column. What is your table schema currently?

Comment: I concur, the `tenantId` should be the leftmost column in all clustered index keys and all predicates and joins should include the `tenantId`.

Comment: Currently it just has a single primary key, and tenantID is just another non-nullable column. i.g EmployeeTable = EmployeeID PK, TenantID... No FK keys are set up currently. I thought with a unique clustered index on PK columns can be specified so it would have to be a composite key i.e. EmployeeID and TenantID are both PK's???

Comment: It would break down like this, Employytable.employeeID would be a nonclustered primary key. You would then have a composite clustered index on tenantid and employeeid. For example: 
`create table EmployeeTable
(
    employeeid int identity(1,1) primary key nonclustered,
    tenantid int,
    firstname varchar(200)
    --... and so on
)

create unique clustered index IXCU__EmployeeTable__tenantId__EmployeeID
on EmployeeTable (tenantid, employeeid)`

Answer (score 1):

For every query that makes use of the multi-tenant nature of your design you will want to have an index that includes the tenantId.  The question is, where in the index structure should tenantId occur? Of course the answer is it depends. Try to build the index so the field with the greatest selectivity comes first.

For example assuming a table with an even distribution across states (50) and with 10 tenants I would build the index as State, then TenantId; for the same table with 1000 tenants I would build the index TenantId, then State.

In practice, both indexes would probable come in handy (let the optimizer sort it out).