# How to index in mongoDB for multi-tenant collections on tenantId attribute

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

We have added an attribute `tenantId` in every mongoDB collection to filter based on tenant. Every document also has an `_id` field. But in some collections the queries are to get all documents based on `tenantId`. The query is like `getAllByTenantId(tenantId)`.

How should we index `tenantId` in such a scenario? I am using springboot mongodb index annotations.

If I use indexes on the `tenantId` field I believe it will not work well because of the low cardinality. What would be the standard way to index in such a scenario or handle multi-tenancy where we have a specific field in a collection to separate tenant.

```
@Indexed
private String tenantId;
```

There is a general question on this for SQL:
[Indexing TenantID in Multi Tenant DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8144933/indexing-tenantid-in-multi-tenant-db)

I am looking if there is a standard pattern (or type of index) in MongoDB for achieving the same.

Comment: If you are querying by tenant id + other fields, prepend tenant id to your existing indexes.

Comment: D.SM there are some collections where the queries are getAllByTenantId(tenantId).. so I was wondering whether the @Index on the tenantId will actually have detrimental effect because of the index creation.. I am looking something like a columnstore index or if there is a standard way of achieving this in MongoDB